# Overflow when reading a file

Tags: c, file, buffer-overflow

When reading a simple file, I keep overflowing and reading bytes out of the file despite making sure I get the size of the file in bytes prior to the read.

Here is my current code:

```
FILE* file;
int error_no = fopen_s(&file, filepath, "r");

if (error_no != 0 || file == 0) {
    std::cout << "Error whilst reading file: " + error_no;
}

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(file);

char* fileAsString = (char*) malloc(size+1);

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(fileAsString, 1, size, file);

fileAsString[size] = 0;

std::cout << "\n" << size << "\n";
std::cout << fileAsString;

fclose(file);
```

I am expecting to open the file, push the stream to the end of the file and use ftell to find the number of characters in the file.

Then I make a string buffer to copy the file's content into.

Then finally I reset the file stream and read it into my string buffer. I complete this by adding the end-of-string character at the end of the buffer.

Sadly this is what I get:

```
114
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}═══════
```

I checked and the file contains 107 characters, which explains the 114 length and 7 '=' characters that shouldn't be there.

The actual file contents are:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Hope this is clear enough!

Comment: Any time you feel the need to use a C-style cast when programming in C++, you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. In this case it's your use of C functions instead of "proper" C++ classes and objects that's the problem. In short don't use `malloc` when programming in C++. And if you want a string use `std::string`.

Comment: Regarding your problem, if you use C++ file streams and `std::string` you only need a couple of lines to read the whole file into a `std::string`, without having to worry about explicit allocations, buffer overflows or the pesky string null-terminator. And the size will be correct.

Comment: The open mode should be `"rb"`. Otherwise you are getting LF->CRLF conversion, which increases the size and corrupts the data.

Comment: As for your problem with the size, `fseek` and `ftell` doesn't care about text or binary files, it will handle all files as binary files. So think again what happens with newline translations in text-files, where newline on Windows is `\r\n` and not only the `\n` you actually store in the buffer. And from this I can tell that it seems your last line in the file doesn't end with a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a file with `"r"` mode, you are reading in text mode and your two-byte `\r\n` line endings are being converted to `\n` strings in memory.  But `ftell` is returning the length of the file in bytes (with each newline counting for two bytes).  But you are marking the end of the string (by setting a null character) according to how  many bytes were in the file, as opposed to how many characters are in the string.  Since you have placed your null terminator past the end of the string, you have one character of junk for each newline in your original file.

Instead, you probably want to preserve the bytes of the original file. To do this, try opening the file in `"rb"` mode to read it in binary mode which should prevent it from changing `\r\n` in the file to `\n` in the string in memory.